# How to bind a complex data structure to Spring Controller

Tags: javascript, spring, bind

I am trying to bind a complex data structure to my controller in spring mvc with javascript.

I have this ViewModel;

```
public class LibraryViewModel{

 private String idLibrary;

 private String nameLibrary;

 private List<Box> listBox;

 //Getters and setters

}
```

And this is the box's class:

List listBox;

```
public class Box{

 private String idBox;

 private List<String> booksNames;

//Getters and setters

}
```

What I want to do?

I want to do the form binding idLibrary and nameLibrary with a form in jsp

```
<form:form modelAttribute = "libraryVM" id="bestForm".../>
```

And listBox get a data injection like with a function made in JavaScript.

```
$('#bestForm').submit(function() {
            completeListBoxInfo();
            $('#organizacion').val(a);
        });
```

But I allways get null mi List in mi controller but I get fine my idLibrary and nameLibrary attributes.

```
@RequestMapping("/save")
    protected void guardar(@RequestParam("libraryFM") LibraryViewModel newLibrary) {
        ...
    }
```

How can I bind the View Model object with the function result of completeListBoxInfo();

Kind regards.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do. Could you explain any further details?

Comment: The might be some problem in the format of your provided data. It's not possible to answer your question without seeing the request content.

Comment: Could you post the whole form?